# Terraform - Referencing loop resources in for_each loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreach, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm creating ECS services using my custom module, which is part of `for_each` loop.
I would like to modify a security group in each service, to allow communication from particular services.

Consider the following ECS services map:

```
locals {
  ecs_services = {
    "hello-world" = {
      container_image = local.ecr_repository_url_map["hello-world"]
      container_port  = "5050"
    }
    "hello-world2" = {
      container_image = local.ecr_repository_url_map["hello-world2"]
      container_port  = "8080"
      allowed_serivces = ["hello-world"] 
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my unsuccessful attempt which is causing:

```
Error: Cycle: module.ecs_service.module.this_ecs_service_task (close), module.ecs_service.module.this_ecs_service_task.var.allowed_security_group_ids (expand), module.ecs_service.module.this_ecs_service_task.module.ecs_service_security_group.var.ingress_with_source_security_group_id (expand), module.ecs_service.module.this_ecs_service_task.module.ecs_service_security_group.aws_security_group_rule.ingress_with_source_security_group_id, module.ecs_service.module.this_ecs_service_task.module.ecs_service_security_group (close), module.ecs_service (close), module.ecs_service.var.allowed_security_group_ids (expand)
```

```
module "ecs_service" {
  source  = "./ecs-service"

  for_each = {
    for name, service in local.ecs_services : name => service
  }

  name = each.key

  container_image = each.value.container_image
  container_port  = each.value.container_port


  allowed_security_group_ids = [for k, v in lookup(each.value, "allowed_services", []) : module.ecs_service[v].security_group_id]
  ...
}
```

In my head, this construction is possible, since resources actually don't reference each other per se, and it's possible to create an order, which doesn't produce any conflict. But clearly there's some Terraform limitation.

Is there a workaround I could implement, which doesn't involve creating module manually per each service?

Comment: "there's some Terraform limitation" - what do you mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Comment: @Marcin yes, I mentioned it just above my 2nd snippet. It's a circular logic issue in the Terraform dependency tree. I have updated the full cycle trace. Apologies if I haven't been clear enough.

Comment: I tried to check your code, but it has more issues. For example you did not define `allowed_services`. I think it should be `allowed_serivces`? I guess you have other similar mistakes which prohibits from replicating your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of your mistakes in the code, you **can't do** what you want to do. For two reasons:

1. TF will create all instances of your `ecs_service` module in **concurrently**, not in succession. So you can't refer to non-existing resources before they get created.
2. Iteration over map is based on **lexicographical**, not the map element insertion order. In your simple example, the order agrees with lexicographical order, but relying on this is a perfect way to have issues later on.

Comment: 1. Yea, I feared that this is how modules are being created - concurrently. This closes the topic. But still looking for a solution, where I can have simple map of services configuration.
2. While I get that maps are lexicographical, behind the scene TF probably creates an ordered list of how resources are created (depends_on, output from other resources). But number 1 closes the topic as I mentioned